# Have someone doing SEO for a website running at Orchard CMS?

Tags: seo, content-management-system, orchardcms

I'm now performing some optimization and SEO activities for my company's website - http://www.pnnsoft.com/ . I'm performing optimization for several years but the website is still performing badly in Google search. It is running on Orchard and I'm starting to think that the issue is in the CMS itself. Have someone worked with this kind of CMS.

Besides, I'm checking the PageSpeed Insights for a website and the score is 62, that is very low. I does all possible things to make the page faster, made the pictures weight small etc, still 62.

Have anyone any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use the caching module. It can greatly improve performance. Other then that, there are various Meta-Information generating modules and the rest is up to you

Answer (score -1):

Since orchard generates pretty straightforward HTML, I would be surprised that the CMS has anything to do with it.

I have had great success with the [Social Media module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.Om.Orchard.SocialMetaTags)  that adds the ability to add open graph tags to any content item. It's a bit manual to add them to each item, but it is the new standard for describing the metadata about a page.

It will also add a thumbnail and other relevant information about a page when posting to Facebook or Slack.

Also be sure to have keyword rich, frequently changing content.